# How to use Jasmine SpecRunner.html with Karma coverage tool

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying to run test coverage of Jasmine tests using karma.

My app is structured in the following manner:

www/js/app/production js files (multilevel directory structure)

www/js/tests/SpecRunner.html **-> here I load the production JS modules that are tested with jasmine - using <script src="../../js/app/abcd.js"></script> tags**

www/js/tests/spec/spec js files (multilevel directory structure)

**This is the karma.conf.js file content:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'www/js/tests/spec/*.js'
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors: { '*.js': ['coverage'] }
  });
};
```

When I run `karma start karma.conf.js` in the command line, I can see that none of the objects I test is loaded.

Main question:

**How do I utilize the SpecRunner.html with Karma?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466651/jasmine-specs-without-specrunner-html-js-dependencies?rq=1 -> simillar question, no answers

Comment: ended up manually adding the js files into the file array  :(